# How to simulate a mouse in c# - without tying up the actual mouse?

Tags: c#

I'm back with a rather interesting question this time.

Is it possible to create your own mouse in your program, so that it'll click on certain areas within your program for you? I'm working on a program that will complete the idiot test automatically, faster than my friend (also using his own program), and I don't know how to create a mouse click inside the actual window, without tying up the mouse. So basically, if you minimized the browser, you could still use your own mouse to do other things, like work in a word document or something.

Anyone have any ideas? I'm completely new to this, so if I'm being stupid don't be afraid to say so.

Comment: Also, I haven't actually begun this project yet, I just want to get a general idea of how I should do the clicking without the mouse, and about how difficult it is (ie. in my experience range at all)

Comment: ok... without source code this can't be really answered, just: it is possible and dependent on what exactly should be clicked inside the same program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoIt3 ( http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/) is your friend for the purpose. Look for C#/COM interface with autoIt3 for more information.

In order to program in c#, (after installing autoit3) you can reference AutoItX3.dll and start using it in your c# project.